# Secure web.config info

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msdeploy

We are working on a ASP.NET MVC site. I am a dev who is also responsible for prod deployments with other members of the team distributed across the globe.

Today I started working on the web.release.config transformation file for production deployment, and it made me thinking that I really don't want other devs to have access to these files since they contain sensitive production information. But, in VS 2010 these files are placed right next to the dev web.config, so if I check them in, then, the rest of the crew will see them.

Is there a recommended way to use VS2010 to apply transformations to web.config files in such a way that these transformation files don't have to be located with the rest of dev files? Or, do I need to use some kind of automated build tools such as NANT or MS Team Server to do that?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I think this helps http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I typically use the src= tag on the web.config connection file to have a separate file for connection strings for production server that the developers don't have access to to keep it secure.  Then in my build process, I grab the webProd.config file from a more secure place and update the server with it.